# Set default registration type for content type

Tags: forms, users, nodes

I created a registration type for a certain content type using the registrations module (https://drupal.org/project/registration).
But the user can select or disable a registration type.

Can you force this registration on a certain content type?

Answer (score 0):

Since Registrations are fields make it a required field. [image]

And then from the default values select the type of registration you want to force for a content type.

[image]